# Developing push-notification system in react

Tags: reactjs, push-notification

I am trying to develop a notification system in a react app  such as if 'user' is demanding a service from 'admin' then I am updating the demands from user in admin_service database. But how should i make sure that admin receives the request from database right away as user makes the request.
I am thinking that in frontend i am suppose to make this rest call (which makes a call to admin_service db to load new demands) constantly.
However i don't think that this is a good solution. 
Any solutions?

Comment: You did not provide enough information about your client application and your requirements. Is the client application running in a browser? Does the *admin* need to receive notifications only when he's using the app or any time? Usually the term *push* notification means that a service *pushes* the notification to the client rather than the client constantly polling the server. And usually this requires using a device specific framework and a cloud messaging service like *firebase*.

Comment: For example... Facebook... How do they show notifications as soon as they receive. I am trying to implement the same in react but not react native for now, so only browsers. I am not understanding how to proceed for that

Comment: There are basically 3 different technologies you can use for on-site notifications. But note that they only work **while having the react app opened**. Long polling, Server-sent events and websockets. You should make yourself familiar with each of those options. A popular framework using websockets is [`socket.io`](https://socket.io/). Websockets basically allow bi-directional communication between the server and the client. This needs to be setup on the server and the client to work. This may or may not work for you. It's hard to tell without more details about your requirements.

Comment: Ohhk. Thanks mate... Will check on tht